# HTTP handlers - when should I use return?

Tags: go

I'm a little confused about http handlers and handling something like errors or redirects.

For example, if I have to redirect because of some conditional check, should I be doing the following:

```
func SomeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
    if thisThing != thatThing {
        log.Print("thisThing not equal to thatThing - redirecting")
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusTemporaryRedirect)
        return // <-- is this necessary?
    }
 }
```

Comment: In your case: No. the function you showed will return implicitly when hitting the last `}`. But most probably you would send some other response after the `if` so: Yes, of course! You sent the redirect and that's all, you're done with this request so return from handling it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rule is: `return` when you're done processing, to prevent further processing.

In your case, a `return` is not necessary, because there is no further processing in your function. If you had further logic, though, you would want to return:

```
func SomeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
    if thisThing != thatThing {
        log.Print("thisThing not equal to thatThing - redirecting")
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusTemporaryRedirect)
        return // <-- is this necessary?
    }
    w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    // ... add a normal response
 }
```

Without a return in this case, you'll send the headers to initiate a redirect, then you'll *also* send a normal JSON response.  That is obviously not what you want, so the `return` is needed.

The astute reader will note that there would be other ways to accomplish this type of control flow.  An `else` would be an option:

```
func SomeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
    if thisThing != thatThing {
        log.Print("thisThing not equal to thatThing - redirecting")
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusTemporaryRedirect)
    } else {
        w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
        // ... add a normal response
    }
 }
```

However, as your conditions grow in complexity, a `return` is often going to be the most readable method. But it is ultimately a style choice at that point.

Comment: `return` instead of `else` is generally considered more idiomatic in Go, and will be suggested by most Go linters if they see an `else` block after an `if` block that ends in a `return`.

Answer (score 0):

`return` is used for preliminary exit from the function and returning value to caller. As it was pointed before if there’s no more instruction function will exit but itself

When to use `return`?

One of key ideas of Go is readability - every program should be easy to read. So Go code is structured vertically - main flow goes as a straight line on the left from top to bottom. It’s often considered as a "good" or "basic" scenario. All diverts from it goes to right. Many diverts often are quite simple - for example it can be error workaround and exit.

For example you have a function whether number is positive:

```
func IsPositive(n int) bool {
    if n <= 0 {
        return false
    }
    return true 
}
```

You may trace a main execution line on the left and catch keywords `IsPositive` below check digression `if ...` and at the bottom `return true`.  As you can see we do not use `else`. We got it “for free” (without visual overloading) as a sole remaining option in our program. I can say functions structured this way require `else` quite rarely. Also you won’t find it very often keyword on standard code.